# Convert Class Instance To Dictionary And Vice Versa

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Let's say I have the class

```
Class foo()
    public bar as string
    public bar2 as string
end class
```

and I want to convert an instance of this class to a dictionary where the key is the variable name and the value is its value. How would I do this?

Also, let's say I have the dictionary

```
dim dict as new Dictionary(of string, string)
dict.add("bar","value")
dict.add("bar2","value2")
```

and want to convert this to an instance of the class "foo" above. How would I do this?

Comment: A Dictionary with just one thing is a bold design decision, but `Foo` could have a `ToKeyValuePair` method that returns a `KeyValuePair` that you add to your dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Reflection, you could do both things you asked. This works on classes with both Properties and Fields (since your example has Fields).

```
Imports System.Reflection

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim myFoo As New foo With {.bar = "barValue", .bar2 = "bar2Value"}
        Dim myDictionary = InstanceToDictionary(myFoo)
        Dim myNewFoo = DictionaryToInstance(Of foo)(myDictionary)
    End Sub

    Public Function InstanceToDictionary(Of T)(instance As T) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
        Dim result As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
        For Each pi As PropertyInfo In GetType(T).GetProperties
            result.Add(pi.Name, pi.GetValue(instance))
        Next
        For Each fi As FieldInfo In GetType(T).GetFields
            result.Add(fi.Name, fi.GetValue(instance))
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

    Public Function DictionaryToInstance(Of T As New)(dictionary As IDictionary(Of String, Object)) As T
        Dim result As New T()
        For Each pi As PropertyInfo In GetType(T).GetProperties
            pi.SetValue(result, Convert.ChangeType(dictionary(pi.Name), pi.PropertyType), Nothing)
        Next
        For Each fi As FieldInfo In GetType(T).GetFields
            fi.SetValue(result, Convert.ChangeType(dictionary(fi.Name), fi.FieldType))
        Next
        Return result
    End Function

End Module

Class foo
    Public bar As String
    Public bar2 As String
End Class
```

[image]